# Как авторизироваться в VK логином и паролем?

Tags: java, vkontakte-api

Есть такой модуль на пайтоне, `vk` называется. С его помощью можно авторизироваться с помощью *логина* и *пароля*:

```
session = vk.AuthSession(app_id=APP_ID, user_login=LOGIN, user_password=PASS) 
vkapi = vk.API(session)
```

Хочу такое же на **java** осуществить, так как приложение делаю не браузерное, и обычный *implicit flow* не подойдет, но все поиски ни к чему не приводят.

Comment: у вашего приложения будет графический интерфейс?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman будет, но встраивать браузер не вариант

Comment: а какую библиотеку вы будете использовать? javafx?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman да, javafx

Comment: там есть [WebView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html), так что ничего встраивать не надо.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman под WebView я и подразумеваю встраивание браузера

Comment: Тогда изучите исходный код модуля на пайтон и повторите его. Но учтите, что вас могу забанить за подобный способ аутентификации.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman понял

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/709320/264488
В низу ответа есть ответ и на Ваш вопрос