# VK api. У объекта audio поле duration всегда 25

Tags: android, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Делаю [запрос](https://vk.com/dev/wall.get), если у поста есть аудиозапись, то вместо нормальной длительности возвращает 25. Я так понял, что это длительность заглушки("Вы используете приложение в котором недоступны аудиозаписи вконтакте..."). Само приложение используется на андроиде, но если сделать запрос не с телефона, используя токен, полученный с телефона, то будет то же самое. Как решить данную проблему?

Comment: Так разве это проблема? API на запрос аудио возвращает заглушку, а на запрос длительности аудио возвращает длительность заглушки. Вроде всё корректно.

Comment: @NickVolynkin А как тогда получить длительность аудио?

Answer (score 1):

ВКонтакте уже длительное время не возвращает аудиозаписи, а методы апи из секции аудио скрыты. Любые сторонние приложения, использующие скрытое апи нелегально, будут удалятся из магазина приложений. Но, если всё же хотите использовать аудио, то реверс-инжиниринг вам в помощь. 
Дизассемблируете официальное приложение, берёте из него client_id и client_secret, смотрите, каким образом оно отправляет запросы и делаете точно также у себя.

Можете дизассемблировать старый WinRT клиент вк для Windows 8. На личном опыте могу сказать, что с лёгкостью можно найти интересующий вас компонент

Answer (score 1):

Он потребует подтвердить токен

А вот о том, как это сделать следует написать целую статью

Берёте, сканируете трафик, ищите пакеты, которые отправляются на этот
адрес(лично у меня их 3 штуки, у Вас может быть по-другому) - android.clients.google.com . Ответ на последний запрос должен быть вида "|token|ID|<цифра>|<много букаф>" или подобное

Далее делаете запрос к методу auth.refreshToken с параметрами access_token, lang='ru', https=1 и с параметром receipt=<вон те много букаф>
Данный запрос вернет новый secret и access_token, который будет валиден для аудиозаписей

- Надо заметить, что надо это делать с [sig](https://vk.com/pages?oid=-1&p=%D0%92%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%81_API)
- Также следует заметить, что access_token надо было получать запросом вида(пробел поставил, чтобы не обрезалось)
  ht tps://oauth.vk.com/token?grant_type=password&username=<логин>&password=<пароль>&2fa_supported=1&scope=all,nohttps&libverify_support=1&client_secret=hHbZxrka2uZ6jB1inYsH&client_id=2274003&device_id=&lang=ru