# Получение данных пользователя VK через токен от приложения

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, token

Не работает получение данных по апи https://api.vk.com/method/users.get если access_token получен через приложение написанное с помощью библиотек VK для смартфонов, если же получаю access_token через апи https://oauth.vk.com/access_token то получение данных работает, как можно получать данные на сервере если access_token сгенерирован библиотекой приложения(VK SDK) ?

Comment: т.е вы получаете token с помощью библиотек, и он не корректен ? или вообще не получаете ?

Comment: получаю, но по такому токену users.get  говорит что токен не корректный

Answer (score 1):

Если Вам нужен token, который сгенерирован как с приложения, то , пожалуйста, прочтите [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/709320/264488) ответ.

В нём указано всё о том, как авторизуется оф. приложение. В том числе и для получения доступа к audio

Comment: Ничего нового помимо ссылки нет -- мне кажется, что логичнее это было оставить в комментариях, либо подумать о том, чтобы оформить дубликатом.

Comment: @AK  данный вопрос, как и ответ, уже более не актуален в связи с изменением vk api.

Comment: Гм, не обратил что вопрос 2017 года :) Но его кто-то триггернул в очередь проверок -- так что ждите ещё десанта проверяющих.